# Can you send server-side events to Facebook Ads?

Tags: facebook-ads-api, google-ads-api

We use Facebook pixel for sending ad-related events. The problem is, some of the events can only be sent server-side, but there doesn't seem to be such functionality. I hoped it might have something similar to [Adwords Offline Conversion Tracking](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2998031?hl=en)

but so far I haven't been able to find anything. Does anybody encountered anything like it? Maybe there is some hack I can use.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Facebook launched a beta version of Offline Conversions for their Marketing API just recently.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/offline-conversions/